# Biblatex and entries with no date

Tags: biblatex

I have a bibliographic entry with no date. I would like this to be printed both in the citation (i.e. in the text) and in the references with "n.d.", otherwise it shouldn't be different from a regular entry.

In the example below, I would like the citations to be

> Lennon (n.d.); Lennon (1972)

and the references to be

> Lennon, John (n.d.). *Peace on earth*.
>
> Lennon, John (1972). *More peace on earth*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes,filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Peace on earth"}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "More peace on earth",
    YEAR = "1972"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcites{lennon}{lennon1972}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add the following hooks to your preamble:

```
\newcommand{\mkbibnodate}{n\adddot d\adddot}
\AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldundef{labelyear}{\restorefield{labelyear}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{labelyear}{\restorefield{year}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}
```

With biber, you can achieve the same result with the source map:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=false]{
      \step[fieldset=date,origfieldval,final]
      \step[fieldset=eventdate,origfieldval,final]
      \step[fieldset=origdate,origfieldval,final]
      \step[fieldset=urldate,origfieldval,final]
      \step[fieldset=eventyear,origfieldval,final]
      \step[fieldset=origyear,origfieldval,final]
      \step[fieldset=urlyear,origfieldval,final]
      \step[fieldset=year,fieldvalue={n.d.},final]
      \step[fieldset=sortyear,fieldvalue={0000}]
    }
  }
}
```

Both of these approaches are style-independent so they should work for `authoryear` and any of its variants.

The above sourcemap is based on the default `labelyear` specification:

```
\DeclareLabelyear{
  \field{year}
  \field{eventyear}
  \field{origyear}
  \field{urlyear}
}
```

Currently `\DeclareLabelyear` does not support literal strings, but something like the following would be useful:

```
\DeclareLabelyear{
  \field{year}
  \field{eventyear}
  \field{origyear}
  \field{urlyear}
  \literal{n.d.}
}
```

I've added a [feature request](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/94) for this at the biblatex github repository.

Comment: A follow-up note: Using the former alternative, ``biblatex`` now also adds ``n.d.`` to the entry type ``@ONLINE``, which is not suitable, since the ``@ONLINE`` entry has a field ``URLDATE`` for this purpose. I assume there's an easy fix for this (one that skips ``@ONLINE`` entries or one that doesn't add ``n.d.`` if the entry has a field for ``URLDATE``), but I wouldn't know how to do it.

Comment: @Sverre `labelyear` has a few fallback values if `year` isn't defined. For the first approach you can just base the test always on `labelyear`. Accounting for fallbacks in second approach gets messy.

Comment: The '\DeclareSourcemap' -method works for me since I am using biber. How do you change the 'n.d.' to 's.a.'?

Comment: Nevermind. The answer was the most obvious; just edit the \step[fieldset=year,fieldvalue={n.d.},final] -line. I forgot to run PdfLatex-Biber-PdfLatex and hence the values did not update.

Answer (score 11):

Please try biblatex 2.6/biber 1.6 development versions from SourceForge. This set up is now the default and there is a new localisation string "nodate" which defaults to "n.d." in all languages currently. `\DeclareLabelyear` is now the more general:

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{event}
  \field{orig}
  \field{url}
  \literal{nodate}
}
```

but you shouldn't need to worry about that unless you are a style author using this macro. With these versions, your example gives the following without any extra coding:

[image]

Changing the "nodate" localisation string for your language will change the "n.d." in both the references and citation.

Comment: Good to hear that the next(?) version of ``biblatex`` and ``biber`` will do this by default. I also hope the appropriate language specific variants will be added in the near future (that is not a pressing need for me). I will myself wait until the next version is released, since I update my packages through ``TexLive``.

Comment: Most language variants for "nodate" have now been incorporated into the biblatex 2.6 dev version.

Comment: It appears as if this still outputs 'n.d.' even though my paper's language is set to 'ngerman'. Any idea why that is so?

Comment: @nerdyllama - check your package options, see especially the `autolang` option which is set to `none` by default. You probably want `autolang=other`

Answer (score 2):

```
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{year}
      {\printtext[parens]{n.d.}}
      {\printtext[parens]{\printdateextra}}}%

\renewbibmacro*{cite:label}{%
  \iffieldundef{label}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printtext{n.d.}}}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{label}}}}
```

Comment: While this works for ``\textcite``, it doesn't work with ``\cite`` or ``\parencite``. In the latter two cases, it only prints ``n.d.``, and not the author's name.