# biblatex - "n.d." when no date given

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to have "(n.d.)" printed for a bibliography entry when no date is given. So far have already found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101210/25683), but the rest of my style code apparently changes something. Could anyone change that specific part? Currently it works just fine for the references, but not at all in the bibliography.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[
language=auto,
style=authoryear-ibid,
backend=biber,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
dashed=false,
doi=false,
citereset=chapter,
maxcitenames=3,
sorting=nyt,
firstinits=true,
uniquename=init,
ibidtracker=true,
maxbibnames=99,
urldate=iso8601,
%mergedate=true, %Audrey https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126584/biblatex-n-d-when-no-date-given?noredirect=1#comment284550_126584
labeldate=true
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%%  parentheses around year in references
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
{}
{% 
\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
\printtext[parens]{%
\printfield{labelyear}%
\printfield{extrayear}}}}}

%% no date given
\newcommand{\mkbibnodate}{n\adddot d\adddot}
\AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldundef{labelyear}{\restorefield{labelyear}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{year}{\restorefield{labelyear}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}

%% correct order of publisher and location
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\newunit
\printlist{publisher}%
\newunit
\printlist{location}%
\newunit}

%%  right order of words 'volume' und 'issue' with comma in front
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% THIS LINE CHANGED to add comma
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}
%taken from standard.bbx
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printtext{%   REMOVED parenthesis here
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}}%
  \newunit}


%% linebreak before URLs and colon before date of last visit
\xpretobibmacro{url+urldate}{\setunit{\newunitpunct\par\nobreak}}{}{}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
urlseen = {last visit\addcolon}
}

%% colon before date of last visit
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}
@Online{ctan,
label         = {CTAN},
hyphenation   = {american},
title         = {CTAN},
subtitle      = {The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network},
url       = {http://www.ctan.org},
urldate   = {2006-10-01}
}
@Book{augustine,
hyphenation   = {american},
author    = {Augusteine, Robert L.},
title         = {Heterogeneous catalysis for the synthetic chemist},
shorttitle    = {Heterogeneous catalysis},
publisher     = {Marcel Dekker},
location      = {New York},
edition={5}
}
@Article{bertram,
author       = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
title        = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces},
journaltitle = jams,
year         = 1996,
volume       = 9,
number       = 2,
pages        = {529-571}
}
@InCollection{hyman,
author       = {Arthur Hyman},
editor       = {O'Meara, Dominic J.},
title        = {Aristotle's Theory of the Intellect and its Interpretation by
                                Averroes},
booktitle    = {Studies in Aristotle},
series       = {Studies in Philosophy and the History of Philosophy},
number       = 9,
publisher    = {The Catholic University of America Press},
location     = {Washington, D.C.},
pages        = {161-191}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is a test for the case if no year was given for \verb+@online+ source.\footcite[See][p. 3]{ctan}.
    \item Another sentence for the parentheses.\footnote{\cite[See][p. 456.]{augustine}}
    \item Words for the \verb+article+-type.\footnote{\cite[See][p. B.]{bertram}}
    \item Soem stuff for \verb+incollection+.\footnote{\cite[See][p. 456.]{hyman}}
\end{itemize}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe by making your example a little "more" minimal, your issue could be more easily located; have you read this great guide on [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: My answer to that post is outdated due to changes in date labels as of 2.6. These are currently under revision as they have introduced a few other issues. A solution will depend on these changes. For now you can load biblatex with `mergedate=false` and use `\restorefield{labelyear}` in the `\AtEveryBibitem` hook.

Comment: @Audrey Unfortunately the year is printed twice for entries with given year/date now. See [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5946798/) for a better MWE due to henrique's request and [here](http://i.imgur.com/tIM67nu.png) for a screenshot of the output.

Comment: This should automatically be the case in biblatex 2.6+ with biber. "nodate" is now a localisation string and it is the default fallback when there is no date in the .bib entry. You shouldn't need any special code to deal with this if you use 2.6+biber 1.6.

Comment: You are right, that is better, but it broke `@online` since now urldate is being used instead of year/date when no year/date is given. See here: [MWE](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5947150/) and [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/pGFD7sJ.png). So far I looked through standard.bbx, english.lbx and authoryear.bbx but couldn't really nail how urldate gets swapped for date.

Comment: Did some runs at it: [MWE](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5950442/) and [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/XUrKBDF). It's at least in the right direction. Might be missing something with decomposing labelyear & urldate, but can't think of what that might be.

Comment: @henry You're likely having trouble getting this answered because the MWE is too long and the underlying question keeps changing. Since you're now OK with using biber, just remove `urldate` as a fallback date label: `\DeclareLabeldate{\field{date}\field{eventdate} \field{origdate}\literal{nodate}}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Audrey said in the comments, the answer is to remove `urldate` as a fallback date label

```
\DeclareLabeldate{\field{date}\field{eventdate} \field{origdate}\literal{nodate}}
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Online{ctan,
label         = {CTAN},
hyphenation   = {american},
title         = {CTAN},
subtitle      = {The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network},
url       = {http://www.ctan.org},
urldate   = {2006-10-01}
}
@Book{augustine,
hyphenation   = {american},
author    = {Augusteine, Robert L.},
title         = {Heterogeneous catalysis for the synthetic chemist},
shorttitle    = {Heterogeneous catalysis},
publisher     = {Marcel Dekker},
location      = {New York},
edition={5}
}
@Article{bertram,
author       = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
title        = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces},
journaltitle = {jams},
year         = 1996,
volume       = 9,
number       = 2,
pages        = {529-571}
}
@InCollection{hyman,
author       = {Arthur Hyman},
editor       = {O'Meara, Dominic J.},
title        = {Aristotle's Theory of the Intellect and its Interpretation by
                                Averroes},
booktitle    = {Studies in Aristotle},
series       = {Studies in Philosophy and the History of Philosophy},
number       = 9,
publisher    = {The Catholic University of America Press},
location     = {Washington, D.C.},
pages        = {161-191}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLabeldate{
  \field{date}
  \field{eventdate} 
  \field{origdate}
  \literal{nodate}
}
\begin{document}
\autocites[See][3]{ctan}[See][456]{augustine}[See][B]{bertram}[See][456]{hyman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]