# Biblatex not showing n.d. if urldate is set

Tags: biblatex

as stated in the title I have a problem with biblatex. If the year is empty, it shows the date given in the urldate entry, instead of showing *n.d.*.

```
@online{Pizza,
 author = {Treccani},
 title = {Pizza},
 url = {https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pizza},
 urldate = {2022-01-01}
}
```

The code above outputs:

- Treccani (2022). *Pizza*. [...]

I would like instead:

- Treccani (n.d.). *Pizza*. [...]

Comment: Remove `urldate` from the labeldate definition. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126584/35864.

Comment: Hi @moewe thanks for the reply. I tried the solution above but it doesn't work quite well.
If the year is given it shows n.d. and push the date after the title of the reference.
For example:

`@online{Schrag2008,
 author = {Schrag, J.},
 title = {Taking Aim: The Power of User Experience Goals},
 year = {2008},
 url = {https://uxpamagazine.org/taking_aim_ux_goals/},
 urldate = {2022-07-20}
}`


It outputs:
- Schrag, J. (n.d.). Taking Aim: The Power of User Experience Goals. 2008. url:
https://uxpamagazine.org/taking_aim_ux_goals/ (visitato il 20/07/2022)
(cit. a p. 23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `labeldate` definition ([ll. 1385-1392 of `biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/868b79fecb7998742eae53d2f81bb637453ceaf7/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L1385-L1392)) looks as follows

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}
```

and takes `urldate` into account.

If you don't want that, add the following to your preamble

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \literal{nodate}
}
```

Comment: Thank you . It worked ^^