# biblatex: show no date instead of urldate

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style

When I print the references, the entry shows the urldate instead of no date. How can I suppress the urldate?

`bibliography.bib`:

```
@misc{test,
    title = {Test},
    url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com},
    urldate = {2022-11-17},
    author = {{SL}}
}
```

Result: Test (2022)
Expected: Test (n. d.)

`packages`:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,giveninits,uniquename=init,maxbibnames=6,urldate=long,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{Available at\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{(Accessed: #1)}
```

I tried the following solutions:
[src](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126584/biblatex-n-d-when-no-date-given)

```
\DeclareLabeldate{\field{date}\field{eventdate} \field{origdate}\literal{nodate}}
```

Which leads to n. d. for entries with valid year field

and this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101171/biblatex-and-entries-with-no-date)

`MWE.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
    @book{mybook,
        title = {Book title},
        author = {Myself, Me},
        year = {2020},
    }
    @misc{test,
        title = {Test},
        url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com},
        urldate = {2022-11-17},
        author = {{SL}}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,giveninits,uniquename=init,maxbibnames=6,urldate=long,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{Available at\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{(Accessed: #1)}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
    Hello \cite{test} and \cite{mybook}
    
\printbibliography[title=References]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `\field{year}` in your `\DeclareLabeldate` definition right after the `\field{date}` so that the legacy field is recognised. This is slightly counter-intuitive, but should be resolved in the upcoming `biblatex` release, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/714.

For now use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  giveninits,
  uniquename=init,
  maxbibnames=6,
  urldate=long,
]{biblatex}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlfrom = {available at},
  urlseen = {accessed},
}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \literal{nodate}
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mybook,
  title  = {Book title},
  author = {Myself, Me},
  year   = {2020},
}
@misc{test,
  title   = {Test},
  url     = {https://tex.stackexchange.com},
  urldate = {2022-11-17},
  author  = {{SL}}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Hello \autocite{test} and \autocite{mybook}

  \printbibliography[title=References]
\end{document}
```

[image: Hello (SL, n.d.) and (Myself, 2020)]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much!