# What does p.d. mean in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I have a biblatex bibliographical reference as follows :

```
@MISC{Constitutionfr35,
  title = {Constitution du 4 octobre 1958 - Article 15},
  owner = {leo},
  timestamp = {2013.09.20}
}
```

Which gives in the pdf file : `Constitution du 4 octobre 1958 - Article 15 p.d.`

What does mean this p.d. ? And how to remove it ?

Comment: Yes, in `french.lbx` one finds `nodate = {{pas\space de\space date}{{}p\adddot d\adddot}},`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of version 2.6 `biblatex` implements a "no date" functionality (see [Biblatex and entries with no date](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101171/35864) and § 4.5.8, p. 165 and § 4.9.2.14, p. 204 of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). If no appropriate field to extract a date from is found (by default these are `date`, `eventdate`, `origdate` and `urldate`), `biblatex` falls back to a `nodate` string. In English `nodate` is "no date"/"n. d.", in French it happens to be "pas de date"/"p. d.", while in German it is "ohne Datum"/"o. D.".

The easiest way to get rid of the `nodate` string is to provide a date; preferably by `date={2012-08-09}` or `year={2012}`, but really via any of the fields listed above.

If this is not acceptable for you - I appreciate that in your example "constitution du 4 octobre 1958 - Article 15 (1958)" or even "constitution du 4 octobre 1958 - Article 15 (4. 10. 1958)" might feel quite redundant, you can add the following code to your preamble

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{urldate}
}
```

In case no appropriate date label is found, the `labeldate` field then remains empty and is not printed.

If you care for a finer treatment of `nodate`, [biblatex: getting rid of ›nodate‹ where it's inappropriate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135672/35864) might help you.