# Remove "n.d." (no date) from online entries without dates in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber, urls

[`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) prints the string `n.d.` (no date) in the bibliography for entries that have no date information in the `.bib` file (as a result of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101171/biblatex-and-entries-with-no-date)).

It didn't use to print `n.d.` for `@online` entries, but in the current version (3.6) it does. My question is, how can I remove all such `n.d.`/`nodate` strings from all `@online` entries, while leaving others alone (as in `@book` in the example below, which should still print `n.d.`)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lennon,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Who did what in the Beatles"}
@online{google,
    TITLE = "Google",
    URL = "https://www.google.com"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcites{lennon}{google}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The answer was updated with a much better solution. See the edit history for the earlier, less elegant approach.

The "nodate" marker is inserted by the labeldate format as fall-back with `\literal{nodate}` at the very end of `\DeclareLabeldate`. We can suppress this for `@online` entries by providing a type-sepcific definition for `\DeclareLabeldate`. With the code below the `labeldate` field will simply come out undefined instead of "nodate" if no suitable date fields are defined for `@online` entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lennon,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Who did what in the Beatles"}
@online{google,
    TITLE = "Google",
    URL = "https://www.google.com"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareLabeldate[online]{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{urldate}
}

\begin{document}
\textcites{lennon}{google}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives
[image: The citations now read "Lennon (n.d.) and Google", similarly in the bibliography: the "(n.d.)" after "*Google*" is gone]