# biblatex: Citation not showing correctly (n.d.)

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chicago

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[letterpaper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}    
\usepackage{framed}                                 
\usepackage{marginnote}                             
\usepackage{graphicx}                               
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}                       
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}                                                                     
\usepackage{perpage}                        
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}     
\usepackage{xcolor}             
\usepackage{sectsty}                                                    
\usepackage{imakeidx}                       
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}            
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeindex   
\MakePerPage[1]{footnote}           

%*********** Citation Style **************%

\usepackage[notes, authordate, backend=biber, autocite = inline]{biblatex-chicago}


%****************************************************************%
\addbibresource{proposal.bib}
```

The code above works, but the citation shows up as:

> (Mearsheimer, n.d.)

From bib file:

```
@book{Waltz,
    Author = {Kenneth N. Waltz},
    Date-Added = {2017-07-03 15:08:26 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-07-03 15:09:40 +0000},
    Keywords = {Structural Realism},
    Publisher = {Waveland Press, Inc.},
    Title = {Theory of International Politics},
    Year = {2010}}
```

With this command, the n.d. is suppressed, but the year does not appear.

```
\usepackage[notes, authordate, nodates=false, backend=biber, autocite = inline]{biblatex-chicago}
```

I would expect the year of publication to be shown in place of n.d. In my `.bib` file it is there and it prints correctly on the References page at the end of the document.

Any advice? Have not found anything online.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126584 OR https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336041

Comment: And maybe show the entry of *Mearsheimer* in the bib file.

Comment: @book{Waltz,
 Author = {Kenneth N. Waltz},
 Date-Added = {2017-07-03 15:08:26 +0000},
 Date-Modified = {2017-07-03 15:09:40 +0000},
 Keywords = {Structural Realism},
 Publisher = {Waveland Press, Inc.},
 Title = {Theory of International Politics},
 Year = {2010}}

Comment: Edit the question please and don't put the code in a comment.

Comment: Try substituting `Year = {2010}` for `date = {2010}`

Comment: Thank you!  I added a field to the bib database called "Date" and populated it, recompiled, and IT WORKED!  Thx!

Comment: @gusbrs Please undelete your answer.  It seems to at least address the question even though it doesn't reproduce the problem (which is rather impossible due to lack of MWE in the question).

Comment: @HenriMenke, the suggestion worked out of a guess, but the explanation makes no sense, given that I could not reproduce the problem. If you really think it's the wisest, at your request, I will undelete the answer but edit and leave a one-liner with the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given discussion in the comments, substituting `Year = {2010}` by `date = {2010}` should be enough.

Comment: A few versions ago date handling was changed in `biblatex`. One consequence was that `\DeclareLabeldate` needed to be changed, it now needs an explicit `\field{year}`, where before `\field{date}` was enough to cover the use of both `year = {2010}` and `date = {2010}`. Since `biblatex-chicago` modifies `\DeclareLabeldate` it could be that the OP is running an outdated version of `biblatex-chicago` where `\field{year}` is not yet included.

Comment: Now we really know what probably was going on. Tanks @moewe!