# Remove "n.d." from online entries without date in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, urls, biblatex-chicago

For an undated website I would like to remove `(n.d.)` from the citation and the reference. I tried to adapt the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336041/remove-n-d-no-date-from-online-entries-without-dates-in-biblatex#336089) to biblatex-chicago but I guess it is some other macros which will need to be redefined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,indexing=true]{biblatex-chicago}
%\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lennon,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Who did what in the Beatles"}
@online{google,
    TITLE = "Google",
    URL = "https://www.google.com"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
    or (test {\iffieldequalstr{labelyear}{nodate}}
        and test {\ifentrytype{online}})}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
    or (test {\iffieldequalstr{labelyear}{nodate}}
        and test {\ifentrytype{online}})}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}}

\begin{document}
\textcites{lennon}{google}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But you want the "n.d" for the book, right?

Comment: @moewe Ideally yes, but if it considerably simplifies the solution I could live without n.d. for books.

Comment: I'll see what I can do, highly customised styles like `biblatex-chicago` and `biblatex-apa` can be much harder to modify than the standard styles.

Answer (score 1):

For the "nodate" detection, `biblatex-chicago` treats a missing `labelyear` and an explicit literal `nodate` inserted by `\DeclareLabeldate` alike, so we can't use the improved answer to [Remove "n.d." (no date) from online entries without dates in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336041/35864).

But `biblatex-chicago` has the option `nodates` (from the [`biblatex-chicago` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf), p. 121)

> `nodates=true`
>   This option means that for all entry types except `inreference`, `misc`, and `reference`, `biblatex-chicago` will automatically provide `\bibstring{nodates}` for any entry that doesn’t otherwise provide a date for citations and for the heads of entries in the list of references. If you set `nodates=false` in your preamble, then the package won’t perform this
>   substitution in any entry type whatsoever. (The bibstring expands to “n.d.” in English.)

Unfortunately, that option applies to all type (save for the three exception listed above), but we can make that option type specific with only a few lines of code. We then set `nodate=false` only for `@online` entries, while all other entries retain the default `nodate=true`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,indexing=true]{biblatex-chicago}
%\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lennon,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Who did what in the Beatles"}
@online{google,
    author = {Victor},
    TITLE = "Google",
    URL = "https://www.google.com"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{nodates}[true]{%
  \settoggle{cms@nodates}{#1}}%

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[online]{nodates=false}

\begin{document}
\textcites{lennon}{google}{baez/online}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The citations read "Lennon (n.d.), “Google,” and Baez and Lauda (2004)". The bibliography entries now start with "Baez, John C., and Aaron D. Lauda. 2004. Higher....", "“Google.”", and "Lennon, John. n.d."]