# Prevent @misc reference to generatie numbering with apa style

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, apa-style, bibliographystyle

When using apa style the bibliography shouldn't be numbered

[image: bib with only @article references]

The above bibliography is made with only @article references, but when I add a @misc reference to reference a website, it adds numbering. The number of the @misc reference is the key I added to the reference, if i don't add the key it uses the three first letters of the reference name.

[image: bib with @MISC reference]

here is the code i used to make the misc reference:

```
@misc{cnsys,
  title = {Ansys Fluent | {Fluid Simulation Software}},
  howpublished = {\url{https://www.ansys.com/products/fluids/ansys-fluent}},
  note = {Accessed: 2023-03-20},
  key={Ansys Fluent}
}
```

My question now is how do I use @misc without it changing my reference style or how should I reference a website without using @misc?

Here is some code to run:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{natbib}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

@article{Boureima2019,
author = {Boureima, Dianda and Ky, Thierry and Ouedraogo, Issaka and KI, Mibiempan and Compaore, Abdoulaye and Compaore, Roger and Bathiebo, Dieudonné},
year = {2019},
month = {04},
pages = {1869-1874},
title = {Experimental Investigation of a Solar Parabolic Trough Cooker},
volume = {11},
journal = {International Journal of Current Research},
url = {https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332182419_Experimental_Investigation_of_a_Solar_Parabolic_Trough_Cooker},
doi = {10.24941/ijcr.34764.03.2019}
}

@article{Steinmann2017,
author = {Steinmann, Wolf Dieter},
doi = {10.1016/J.RSER.2016.10.065},
file = {:C\:/Users/matth/OneDrive - KU Leuven/unif/thesis/Literatuur_solarcooker/pdf/Thermo-mechanical concepts for bulk energy storage.pdf:pdf},
issn = {1364-0321},
journal = {Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews},
keywords = {Bulk energy storage,CAES,Compressed heat energy storage,Pumped thermal energy storage,Thermal energy storage,Thermo-mechanical energy storage},
month = {aug},
pages = {205--219},
publisher = {Pergamon},
title = {{Thermo-mechanical concepts for bulk energy storage}},
volume = {75},
year = {2017}
}

@misc{cnsys,
  title = {Ansys Fluent | {Fluid Simulation Software}},
  howpublished = {\url{https://www.ansys.com/products/fluids/ansys-fluent}},
  note = {Accessed: 2023-03-20},
  key={Ansys Fluent}
}
```

Comment: As always you should provide code others can copy and test as is. What exactly does `apa style` mean in this context. Additionally since you haven't provided any code, we cannot see whether you are using `biblatex` or normal `bibtex`.

Comment: I added some code, I am extremely new to latex and I'm using a huge template from my university so I don't know what a MRE should contain. Also I'm pretty sure I'm using bibtex

Comment: @Fonduemeh Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/3225#3225 A MRE should be a short, but compilable test document which allows is to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Note: `apalike` is not a real APA style. IMHO best solution to get APA7 is `biblatex` + [`biblatex-apa`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa). Best solution to get APA6 is `biblatex` + [`biblatex-apa6`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa6). To have only some author-year style you can, e.g., use `biblatex` standard style `authoryear` or [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) style `ext-authoryear`.

Comment: The code generates an error message: "Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style". Presumably you compile in a mode that ignores errors, meaning there is an implicit <return> pressed and the compilation switches to numeric.

Comment: In general make sure you always read error messages and fix the problems instead of ignoring them. Here it is sufficient to add `year={n.d.}` to the misc entry.

Comment: To improve the formatting in the text (now the periods are stripped) you can take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597189/references-with-n-d-no-date-using-natbib-with-apalike.

Comment: Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649511/how-to-have-author-n-d-using-misc-in-natbib?noredirect=1&lq=1 is maybe easier.